# Looking for alternative sortable JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing

From [SwingLabs Forum](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=153735&tstart=0Blockquote), it seems that there is no plan to make JXTreeTable sortable.

From the thread, another alternative is

`"You could use JXTable & GlazedLists TreeList to make a TreeTable"`

However, I prefer to have a API which is ready with sortable feature, instead of the need of building by hand.

I was wondering, is there any alternative library to JXTreeTable? My client start to complain JXTreeTable is not sortable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some of the alternative I had found :

http://svn.chorem.org/svn/jtimer/tags/jtimer-1.0-beta4/src/java/org/codelutin/jtimer/ui/treetable/sorting/

I had compiled it using SwingX 0.9.6, not perfect. Some more modification works is required.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [JideSoft](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) TreeTable which is sortable on multiple columns. Article about it [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-). This is not a free product however, but a very good library of Swing components for a reasonable price.